# How to get only distinct values from joined multiple tables

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

[Here i want to show only distict values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GXNUe.png)

```cs
var projects = (from dtid in db.Types.Where(dtid => dtid.Site == 1)
                    join diid in di on dtid.TypeId equals diid.TypeId
                    join dicid in dic on diid.DonationId equals dicid.DonationId
                    join eeid in ee.Where(eeid => eeid.IsActive == true) on dicid.ExEnId equals eeid.ExEnId
                    join cid in c on eeid.CoId equals cid.CoId
                    where dtid.DonationTypeId == id                             

                    select new Newmodel
                    {
                        countries = cid,
                        exEn = eeid,
                        donationItemCountries = dicid,
                        donation = diid,
                        types = dtid                               

                    }).Distinct().ToList().Take(100) ;

return View(projects);
```

I have a multiple table with some related data which I want to show only unique country to the view using the .NET core entity framework Here is the code.

Models

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Web;
using System.Collections;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

namespace website.Models

{
    public class Newmodel
    {

        public Types types { get; set; }
        public Donation donation { get; set; }
        public DonationCountries donationCountries { get; set; }
        public ExEn exEn { get; set; }
        public Countries countries { get; set; }


    }
}
```

Comment: By which property do you want to compare your objects?

Comment: Could you share the detailed models?

Comment: @Rena Please check my model is there any mistake ?

Comment: Hi @MohamedAbubakkar,This is just a view model.I think you need to share your `Types`,`Donation`,`DonationCountries`,`ExEn` and `Countries`  models relationship with simple code design.

Answer (score 0):

Distinct compared through *what*? Calling `Distinct()` without and [`IEqualityComparer`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.iequalitycomparer-1?view=netcore-3.1) does the same as if you normally use `==`, meaning it looks if the references are equal. I'm guessing you want to compare by country name or country id, which means you'll need a custom `IEqualityComparer`, luckily enough they're quite easy to implement:

```cs
class NewmodelEqualityComparer : IEqualityComparer<Newmodel>
{
    public bool Equals(Newmodel n1, Newmodel n2)
    {
        // Replace '.countries' with whatever property you want to compare
        return n1.countries == n2.countries;
    }

    public int GetHashCode(Newmodel n)
    {
        return n.GetHashCode()
    }
}
```

Your call to `Distinct` then needs to simply pass this as its equality comparer, like so:

```cs
.Distinct(new NewmodelEqualityComparer()).Take(100).ToList();
```

Notice how I switched the positions of `Take` and `ToList`, this is because if you `ToList` first and then `Take` 100 the whole underlying original List will be processed and then 100 will be taken. We can make this a lot more efficient by first taking 100 and then converting the underlying collection to a list, saving potentially thousands of calls to `Distinct`. This is due to [deferred execution](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/deferred-execution-example) provided by `IEnumerable` and LINQ